# Values are not updating automatically in angular 6?

Tags: angular, web-services, angular6, angular-observable

I have a dropdown with values fetched from DB. Values are subscribed in the component.
However, when new select options are added in DB, dropdown values are not updated automatically.

**component.html**

```
     <select name="menu_parent"  class="form-control not_chosen">
      <option *ngFor="let menu of resultMenus" value="{{ menu.id }}">{{menu.title}}</option>
    </select>
```

**component.ts**

```js
    ngOnInit() { 
        this.data.showMenus()
         .subscribe(data =>{
            this.resultMenus =  data.data;     
          }
      );
    }
```

**Service**

```js
   showMenus(){ 
         this.ctrURL    = API_URL+"menu"; 
         var localStore =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

         headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStore.token);

          return this.http.get(this.ctrURL,'',{ headers: headers })
             .pipe(map(data => { return data.json(); }));
         }
```

Comment: In order for your browser to update automatically when you add data to your DB, you will need to use websockets. Without it, you can't update your data automatically. BaaS such as firebase offer built-in websockets if you want to try it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use timer to update data.

```
component.ts

import { timer } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 5000).subscribe( t => {
        this.data.showMenus().subscribe(data => { this.resultMenus = data.data; });
    });
}
```

This will cause the update of your options list every 5 secons.